# How to withdraw from multiple contracts?

Tags: solidity

Thank you for watching this topic.
I'm not sure how I can withdraw my balance from multiple contracts.

The situation is like this.
1)People have rights to withdraw each fund.
2)funds are stored at multiple accounts. (e,g A~Z)
3)There is no priority for each account (Withdrawing from any order is ok)

Comment: can you put some more thought into explaining the situation? It makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A contract can only modify its own balance it cannot modify another contract/account balance.

If you want to withdraw from several contract you can make separate transaction to each contract.

Another possibility is to create a "manager" contract that will manage the contracts on your behalf. When you want to withdraw you send a transaction to the "manager" then it will issue withdraws to the child contracts.